# Latin word for "liar"

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a succinct pronoun for a person who is a liar? You could make a phrase for a person who lies using *mentior*, or construct a sentence about the lie itself with *mendacium*, but what a single word for a person who is a Liar? It's hard to imagine that the Romans did not have a specific pronoun for this, but I have yet to find one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=mendax&la=la#lexicon), the adjective *mendax* was used as a noun to mean *liar*:

> I.given to lying, mendacious; subst., **a liar**.
>
> I. Lit.: “mendacem esse adversus aliquem,” Plaut. Poen. 1, 2, 188:
>   “cum mendaci homini, ne verum quidem dicenti, credere soleamus,” Cic.
>   Div. 2, 71, 146: “Carthaginienses fraudulenti et mendaces,” id. Agr.
>   2, 35, 95: “aretalogus,” Juv. 15, 16.—**As subst.: mendax , dācis, m., a
>   liar.**—Prov.: “mendacem memorem esse oportet,” a liar should have a
>   good memory, Quint. 4, 2, 91.— Comp.: “Parthis mendacior,” Hor. Ep 2,
>   1, 112.—Sup.: “mendacissimus,” the greatest liar, Plaut. Rud. 3, 4,
>   48.—With gen.: “si hujus rei me mendacem esse inveneris,” Plaut. As. 5, 2, 4.—With dat.: “saepe fui mendax pro te mihi,” Ov. H. 2, 11.—With
>   in and acc.: “in parentem,” Hor. C. 3, 11, 35; for which adversum,
>   Plaut. Poen. 1, 2, 188.— With in and abl.: “in tenui farragine,” Pers.
>   5, 77.—

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 11):

A good word for "liar," which can be used either as an adjective or as a noun alone, is [*mendax, -cis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmendax).

Here's Plautus in *Truculentus*:

> D. Redin an non redis?
> A. Vocat me quae in me potest plus quam potes.
> D. Vno verbo
> A. Eloquere.
> D. Mittin me intro?
> A. **Mendax** es, abi. unum aiebas, tria iam dixti verba, atque ea **mendacia**.

My quick translation:

> D: Are you coming back or not?
> A: Someone is calling me who has more power over me than you.
> D: One word!
> A: Speak.
> D: Are you sending me in?
> A: You're a **liar**, go away. You said "one," but you just said three [in English: five] words--and **lying** words too!

Here's Cicero:

> At quid interest inter periurum et **mendacem**?
>
> What's the difference between a perjurer and a **liar**?